# Setting no scrolling Indicator?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am making a `tableView`, but I don´t want the scrolling indicator and there seems to be no way to setting for setting the indicator to none. Is any other way to do this?

Comment: I tried doing it programmatically and I read the documentation for UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle, but it only gives you the option for black, white and default indicator styles.

Comment: see my answer -- you can set it to invisible using the methods I mention.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yep, just use:

```
[tableView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[tableView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
```

`UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, so you get access to the latter's properties, and relevant setters and getters. Here's a link to [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/showsHorizontalScrollIndicator) with a bit more info.

Comment: Well, that didn´t seem hard! Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Hope this answers the question :)

Answer (score 2):

For UIScrollView in swift version

```
scrollView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
scrollView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
```

As,UITableView inherits form UIScrollView so try for UITableView

```
self.myTable.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
self.myTable.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
```

Hope this help someone.